# Build stats function on date

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have Cloudant db, which is actually couchdb.
I have a date field in my documents and I need to get statistic similar to what _stats provide on numeric fields (e.g. min, max, avg, count). Is there a way to do this in cloudant?

I've in map function convert to timestamp and send it to reduce. Is it right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB and Cloudant allow the indexing of dates as compound keys in a MapReduce index e.g. generating keys like this:

```
[ 2014, 5, 21]
```

where each element of the array represents the year, month and day of your stored date, respectively.

This can be achieved in map function like so:

```
function(doc) {
  if (typeof(doc.date) === "string") {
    var d = new Date(doc.date);
    emit([ d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDay()], null);
  }
}
```

With a `_count` reducer, this index can be used with the `group_level` parameter to produce comprehensive analysis of time-series data e.g

- counts by year
- counts for a given year by month
- counts for a given year by day
- counts by year, month & day

By adding a numeric value into the second parameter of the `emit`, and using `_stats`, time-series statistics can be easily extracted from the index and grouped as above.